# Exponentiation involving high powers of 2.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How to calculate

$2^{987}-2^{986}=?$

without using a calculator?

Answer: $2^{986}$

Comment: Check to see if my edit reflects what was originally intended for the question.  As it was originally written, it was very difficult to understand what was meant.  $2^{987}-2^{987}=0$ of course, since $x-x=0$ for all $x$.  Please when posting a question, check to see that the tags you use are in fact relevant to the question.  Simple-Groups has nothing to do with this and is a *much* more advanced topic.

Comment: What is the GCF of $2^{987}$ and $2^{986}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you mean to ask "$2^{987}-2^{986}=?$".  Note that $2^{987}=2\cdot 2^{986}$ and that $2x-x = x$.

So:

$$2^{987}-2^{986} = 2\cdot 2^{986}-2^{986} = (2-1)2^{986} = 1\cdot 2^{986}=2^{986}$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice, the following steps $$2^{987}-2^{986}$$$$\iff 2^{986+1}-2^{986} $$$$\iff  2\times 2^{986}-2^{986}$$$$\iff 2^{986}(2-1)=\color{red}{2^{986}}$$

Answer (score 1):

In greater generality, $b^n-b^m$ (for $n>m$) equals
$$b^{(n-m)+m}-b^m$$
$$=b^{n-m} \times b^m-b^m$$
$$=(b^{n-m}-1) \times b^m$$
as, for example, $10^9-10^6=999\times 10^6$. 
If $n-m=1$, this clearly reduces to
$$(b-1) \times b^m$$
and, if (additionally) $b=2$, it reduces further to
$$b^m\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ i.e.,\ \ 2^m$$